# Delete table row (from a loop an api) by using curl

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, api, curl

I am using a for-loop for displaying data from an API inside a table:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($return['data']); $i++){
    echo "<tr><td>".$return['data'][$i]['data_id']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".'<button id="delete" class="btn btn-danger" value="'.$return['data'][$i]['data_id'].'" type="text">Delete</button>'."</td></tr>";
}
```

The result is a table that shows the `data_id` and the delete button in a row. Now, I want to be able to delete the item by sending the `data_id` to `curl-> delete` (API) code when the delete button clicked!
Or run below code on the delete button clicked.

`curl --include \
         --request DELETE \
         --header "<secret key>" \
         https://example.com/api/v1/data/{data_Iid}?app_id={appId}`

and I need to include the `data_id` from the loop and pass it to the curt delete code. I used a `onClick` function to get the value of `data_id` but it just shows only the first `data_id` value for each delete button.

How can I achieve my goal and be able to pass the right `data_id` to curl delete code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For performance reasons I 'd place an event listener on the table. One JavaScript event listener can catch all clicks on a button. Have a look at the following example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Button Value Event Listener</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="my-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Spalte 1</th>
                <th>Spalte 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Wert 1</td>
                <td>
                    <button value="1" name="delete[]">Mein Button</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Wert 2</td>
                <td>
                    <button value="2" name="delete[]">Mein Button</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        <script>
            var table = document.getElementById('my-table');
            table.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                var target = event.target;

                if (target.tagName = 'BUTTON' && target.value) {
                    // remove and place your ajax request here
                    console.log(target.value);
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

With this example you 'll get all values you 've placed in your for-loop for the buttons. Please make sure, that `$return['data'][$i]['data_id']` is set and contains the value you expect.

In the geiven example your id is just logged in the console. Please replace the `console.log` with your asynchronous javascript request (AJAX).

Comment: OK, I did, also I am running an error on ajax, can you help me with that?. this is my ajax code inside your if:` if (target.tagName = 'BUTTON' && target.value) {$.ajax({url:"delete.php", data: $(this).target.value, type: POST", dataType: "json",  success: function (data) {  
                $('#resultback').addClass("alert alert-success").html('it's been canceled succesfully! ');
 } });  }`